# How to divide an OpenCV Mat in rectangular sub-regions?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, rect

I want to divide a simple `Mat` (200x200) in different regions (10x10). 
I make 2 loops, then I create a `Rect` where I indicate the variables I want in each iteration `(x, y, width, height)`. Finally, I save this region of the image inside a `vector` of `Mat`s.

But something is wrong with my code:

```
Mat face = Mat(200, 200, CV_8UC1);
vector<Mat> regions;
Mat region_frame;
int width = face.cols * 0.05;
int heigth = face.rows * 0.05;
for(int y=0; y<=(face.rows - heigth); y+=heigth)
{
    for(int x=0; x<=(face.cols - width); x+=width)
    {
        Rect region = Rect(x, y, x+width, y+heigth);
        region_frame = face(region);
        regions.push_back(region_frame);            
    }
}
```

The problem is just in the final step, it's not working with size of the new `region_frame` I try to create. It's increasing with each iteration number of cols.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You just need to correct: `Rect region = Rect(x, y, width, heigth);`

Comment: Uffff!!! terrible mistake! I imagined it would be obvious... Thanks a lot for the helpness!!

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but: since width and height are ints and face.cols and face.rows are ints, wouldn't it be better to calc width as face.cols / 20, just so its all in the same domain (ints) rather than doing that math with a float (or a double)?

Comment: @Octopus since you're casting to integer the result is  the same, but you're absolutely correct.

Comment: Yes, what you say is razonable. I gonna do it. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV [Rect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect) can be constructed as:

```
Rect(int _x, int _y, int _width, int _height);
```

So you need to change the line in your code as:

```
Rect region = Rect(x, y, width, heigth);
```

It seems that you instead passed the coordinates of the top left and bottom right corners. If you want to do so, use this other constructor:

```
Rect(const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2);
```

and you can do like:

```
Rect region = Rect(Point(x, y), Point(x+width, y+heigth));
```