# OpenCV, cut pieces from image

Tags: java, android, opencv, mat

I want to cut 16 pieces from image. I am using `OpenCV` and method `submat`.

```
    List<Mat> listOfPieces = new ArrayList<Mat>();

    Mat mat = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap1, mat);

    int x = mat.cols()/4;
    int y = mat.rows()/4;

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){             
            Rect roi = new Rect(i*x ,j*y, (i+1)*x, (j+1)*y);
            Mat submat = mat.submat(roi);
            listOfPieces.add(submat);
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
10-06 12:42:19.842: E/cv::error()(18420): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const Rect&), file /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 323
```

I checked my valuable `roi`, if that is not bigger than dimensions of mat. This code crashes in second cycle of for.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870430/how-to-divide-an-opencv-mat-in-rectangular-sub-regions/32870595#32870595). It's C++ but it can be easily ported.

Comment: You should use the `Rect` constructor that accepts top-left and bottom-right `Point`s

Comment: or you set width to mat.cols/4 and height to mat.rows/4 and only change x and y pos of the rect ;) But anyways be sure that your image dimensions are a multiple of 4 in both directions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Rect` [constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Rect.html#Rect(org.opencv.core.Point,org.opencv.core.Point)) that accepts two `Point`, top-left and bottom-right:

```
Rect roi = new Rect(new Point(i*x ,j*y), new Point((i+1)*x, (j+1)*y));
```