# OpenCV Split Image into Rectangles

Tags: c++, opencv

I have one image and I want it to be split into even rectangles so far I have this code but I keep crashing and I am not sure why.

```
        int cells = 10;
        int rows_to_process = image.rows / cells;
        int cols_to_process = image.cols;

        cv::Mat img;
        std::vector<cv::Mat> imageSections(cells);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        cout << imageSections.size() << endl;
        for(int i=0; i<image.rows/rows_to_process; i++)
        {   
            cout << "i is: " << i << " x is: " << x << endl;
            imageSections[i] = image(cv::Rect(x, y, cols_to_process, rows_to_process));
            x += rows_to_process;
        }
```

I have tested outputting just `x` and I get the dimensions in equal increments from 0 to the size of the image. I was hoping increasing x to the next point I want to start from would work but I am constantly crashing. Does anyone have any idea as to why?

My error comes up in terminal as

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat,
```

Comment: what kind of error message do you get while crashing? Why are you iterating over rows  but increase x?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to divide an OpenCV Mat in rectangular sub-regions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870430/how-to-divide-an-opencv-mat-in-rectangular-sub-regions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this (didn't test it):

```
    int cell_Height = image.rows / 10;
    int cell_width = image.cols;

    std::vector<cv::Mat> imageSections(rows_to_process);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for(y=0; y+cell_Height<image.rows; y+=cell_Height)
    {   
        cout << y << endl;
        imageSections[i] = image(cv::Rect(x, y, cell_Width, cell_Height));
    }
```

Comment: sorry, I just edited my question to show my new code and the error message

Comment: I appologize, I used a version of this but still mixed up x and y, it works now

Comment: after thinking: with my code you might miss some parts of the image. use y+cell_Height<=image.rows instead.