# Split image in python based on custom defined mask

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have several images with each image having grid of small images with different sizes with white background. I want to separate each small image from the bigger grid image and save it separately . How can I achieve this in python ?
content and size of small images keeps on changing with large image to image, only thing which is constant is white background to separate each small image as shown below.
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFvOF.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please work through tutorials before asking. this site is intended for question that haven't been asked before. this one has been asked before. one variation of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091012/how-to-split-an-image-into-m-x-n-tiles-from-left-to-right-and-from-top-down-and another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997256/opencv-split-image-into-rectangles

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: I guess you didn't clearly understand what i wanted to ask. Its not simple straight forward split in rectangle, I do not want a fixed size split. images will have different size and shape grid i want to split it based on the images . I have 3k images none image has same grid it keeps on changing image to image. SPlit rectangle are to be created based on white background